# PHP - str_replace returns original string

Tags: php, ajax

I'm building a simple JS terminal shell emulator which posts its commands via AJAX to PHP.
Please leave security aside, this is only for learning and demo purposes.
Now my problem is, str_replace() won't work as expected, in fact, it returns the unchanged input string. It should work like this:
`The name of this host is $hostname` --> `Yes, this string contains a variable` --> `Replace $hostname with testserver` --> return `The name of this host is testserver`

What am I doing wrong?

This is my respond script for `echo` and `export`:

```
<?
// get environment variables from JSON
$vars = json_decode(file_get_contents('environment.json'), true);

// get request params
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

switch ($action) {

case 'echo':
    $cmd = $data;

        // if the string in question contains a variable, eg. "the time is $time"
        if (strpos($cmd,'$')) {
        $output = '';

        // for each environment variable as variable => value
        foreach ($vars as $var => $val) {

            // replace every variable in the string with its value in the command
            $output = str_replace($var,$val,$cmd);
        }
        echo $output;
    } else { 

        // if it does not contain a variable, answer back the query string 
        // ("echo " gets stripped off in JS)
        echo $cmd; 
    }
break;

case 'export':

    // separate a variable declaration by delimiter "="
    $cmd = explode('=',$data);

    // add a $-sign to the first word which will be our new variable
    $var = '$' . array_shift($cmd);

    // grab our variable value from the array
    $val = array_shift($cmd);

    // now append everything to the $vars-array and save it to the JSON-file 
    $vars[$var] = $val;
    file_put_contents("environment.json",json_encode($vars));
break;
}
```

Comment: Please show the contents of environment.json

Comment: The reason is not to be found in your use of str_replace, so please post the combination `$var`, `$val` and `$cmd` you use.

Comment: Beware with `strpos`, if the word you are searching for is in the first place, it will return `0` and not `false`, so you should use `if (strpos($cmd,'$')) !== false`

Comment: IMHO It would be smarter to create a separate object or an array of closures and address the keys as command names instead of using a switch with logic.

Comment: @Alexander, Sal00m, hd: environment.json contains `{"$hostname":"testserver","$test":"123"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better using :

```
if (strpos($cmd,'$') !== false) {
```

Then, every single replace will take the "first" data as its input data. You should proceed like this :

```
    $output = $cmd;

    // for each environment variable as variable => value
    foreach ($vars as $var => $val) {

        // replace every variable in the string with its value in the command
        $output = str_replace($var, $val, $output);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. But I don't understand why, could you explain? That'd be great...

Comment: Each time you're running the loop again, you're taking the "initial" data ($cmd), and replace in it. So, each time you're looping, you're losing the previous changes you've made on the previous loop.